# Using nats with angular to discuss with Hemerajs microservices server

Tags: node.js, angular, nats.io

I need a piece of advice.
Indeed I am writing an Hemerajs ([Hemerajs](https://hemerajs.github.io/hemera/)) server application couple with a NATS ([NATS](https://nats.io/)) messaging server.
Moreover I'd like to plug an Angular 6+ front application on this server through the NATS pub/sub system.
However I did not find any package or help for using nats with angular.

May I misunderstood pattern messaging behavior, perhaps the messaging system is only internally of microservices server and the communication between angular and node must be with REST API ?

Could you help me for finding the correct package or the correct way to implement this please ?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing there is no official Angular client and ts-nats was written for node.js aka server side.

There are

https://github.com/isobit/websocket-nats
and
https://github.com/isobit/ws-tcp-relay

But they had no updates for 3 years. I'm not sure if websocket-nats was written for nats v1 or v2.

The client protocol is documented here: https://docs.nats.io/nats-protocol/nats-protocol and the following page talks about implementing your own client.

So far nats seems to be for service to service communication only, since there are no official clients for browsers.